TinyMCE Typescript React : Selector type is set as undefined
I have a tinymce editor in my react project (Self hosted - version 6.8.2).
So I was looking through the docs and trying out some stuffs and I saw this 'selector' which can be used inside init.
But when I try to add it like this :
selector: 'textarea',

Then the typescript error shows :
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.

So when I checked I found out that the type the gave to the selector is:
selector?: undefined

Does anyone know anything about this? Or is there any workaround for this?
